# AlertDialog and finishing and launching activity causes a weird crash (segfault)

Tags: android

I have a project which is sometimes experiencing an issue.

Below is where the problem is:

```
UserInterfaceManager uiManager = new UserInterfaceManager(ConnectedDBManagerHost.this);
                if (uiManager.showYesNoDialog(getString(R.string.are_you_sure_you_want_to_disconnect_the_current_database), getString(R.string.are_you_sure), false))
                {
                    ConnectionsManager.connectedDatabase = null;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
```

The error I get is:

```
6-27 20:39:30.792 7067-6937/? A/google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
06-27 20:39:30.792 7067-6937/? A/google-breakpad: V WebView:52.0.2743.100
06-27 20:39:30.792 7067-6937/? A/google-breakpad: O A x86 04 i686 Android/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.1.1/NYC/3756122:userdebug/test-keys
06-27 20:39:30.792 7067-6937/? A/google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 2.0 (4.5.0 NVIDIA 378.78)|Google (NVIDIA Corporation)|Android Emulator OpenGL ES Translator (GeForce GTX 760/PCIe/SSE2)
06-27 20:39:30.793 7067-6937/? A/google-breakpad: H 12C00000 BF8BF000 0041 15473000 5374A000 0C:0B 0D:06 0E:03 0F:03 11:04 12:04 13:03 14:03 15:03 16:03 17:06 18:06 19:05 1A:03 1C:02
06-27 20:39:30.793 7067-6937/? A/google-breakpad: S 0 BF8BADF0 BF8BA000 00005000
6-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/sdk_google_phone_x86/generic_x86:7.1.1/NYC/3756122:userdebug/test-keys'
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG: pid: 6937, tid: 6937, name: ns.myapp  >>> com.mycompany.myapp <<<
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x57
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000057  ebx a9237e6c  ecx 7bbc4824  edx 00000000
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     esi 7bbc4824  edi 00000000
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 0000003b  xss 0000007b
06-27 20:39:30.874 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     eip a922d33e  ebp bf8baf38  esp bf8badf0  flags 00210202
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0001933e  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper9pollInnerEi+1262)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00018d84  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Looper8pollOnceEiPiS1_PPv+68)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000d41f3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android18NativeMessageQueue8pollOnceEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjecti+77)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 000d4264  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 01d35c9c  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1584000) (android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce+136)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 01d37853  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1584000) (android.os.MessageQueue.next+223)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 01d31c1a  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1584000) (android.os.Looper.loop+342)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0162b375  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1584000) (android.app.ActivityThread.main+401)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00109432  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00112de9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+313)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 005105d5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+101)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00512514  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art12InvokeMethodERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectS4_S4_j+1540)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 00469530  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Method_invokeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_S3_+96)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #13 pc 005deb9c  /system/framework/x86/boot.oat (offset 0x520000) (java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke+168)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #14 pc 023803d0  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1584000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run+124)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #15 pc 0238141e  /system/framework/x86/boot-framework.oat (offset 0x1584000) (com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main+1274)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #16 pc 00109432  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+418)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #17 pc 00112de9  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art9ArtMethod6InvokeEPNS_6ThreadEPjjPNS_6JValueEPKc+313)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #18 pc 005105d5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL18InvokeWithArgArrayERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_8ArgArrayEPNS_6JValueEPKc+101)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #19 pc 00510299  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art17InvokeWithVarArgsERKNS_33ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnableEP8_jobjectP10_jmethodIDPc+393)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #20 pc 003f807e  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art3JNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDPc+958)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #21 pc 001417d1  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI11CallMethodVEPKcP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDPcNS_9Primitive4TypeENS_10InvokeTypeE+4513)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #22 pc 00132f8c  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art8CheckJNI21CallStaticVoidMethodVEP7_JNIEnvP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDPc+108)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #23 pc 00070ad1  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7_JNIEnv20CallStaticVoidMethodEP7_jclassP10_jmethodIDz+41)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #24 pc 0007438e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcRKNS_6VectorINS_7String8EEEb+782)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #25 pc 00001b55  /system/bin/app_process32
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #26 pc 0001532c  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+108)
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #27 pc 0000144c  /system/bin/app_process32
06-27 20:39:31.063 7068-7068/? A/DEBUG:     #28 pc 00000004  <unknown>
06-27 20:39:31.380 1616-7073/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 6600)
06-27 20:39:31.383 1616-7073/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
06-27 20:39:31.385 1616-7073/system_process E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 56)
06-27 20:39:31.407 1616-1716/system_process E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=39, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
06-27 20:39:31.407 1616-1716/system_process E/ConnectivityService: RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ LISTEN id=40, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED&FOREGROUND] ]
06-27 20:39:31.407 1616-1689/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '5a5d900 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-27 20:39:31.408 1616-1689/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '6fbf281 PopupWindow:15bf3cb (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-27 20:39:31.408 1616-1689/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel 'ccd4cd8 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.ConnectedDBManagerHost (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
06-27 20:39:31.408 1616-7073/system_process E/NativeCrashListener: Unable to report native crash
                                                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 1
                                                                       at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityStack.java:4995)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2885)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.handleAppCrashLocked(AppErrors.java:590)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.makeAppCrashingLocked(AppErrors.java:477)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplicationInner(AppErrors.java:353)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.AppErrors.crashApplication(AppErrors.java:305)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:13476)
                                                                       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
06-27 20:39:31.413 7076-7082/? E/art: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
06-27 20:39:31.793 1326-1381/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
06-27 20:39:32.599 7076-7162/com.mycompany.myapp E/libEGL: validate_display:99 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)

                                                                            [ 06-27 20:39:32.602  7076: 7162 D/         ]
                                                                            HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x80179280, tid 7162
```

I think I've narrowed it down to the `uiManager.showYesNoDialog()` which is as follows:

```
public boolean showYesNoDialog(String message, String title, boolean isCancelable)
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message mesg)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(isCancelable);
        builder.setTitle(title);
            builder.setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                        {
                            dialogResult = true;
                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialogResult = false;
                            handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage());
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
            try
            {
                Looper.loop();
            }
            catch (RuntimeException ex)
            {
                Log.d("Dialog Error", ex.toString());
            }
        return dialogResult;
    }
```

The method above is used in a library of mine in many places throughout this particular app and another app we have without any issue.

With the showYesNoDialog being called I consistently get this error (although not every time, but more often than not) but if I remove this method call, just do the intent stuff I can't replicate it so I'm pretty sure the showYesNoDialog method is the problem, but I don't get why its having a problem here, and no where else.

Has anyone else experienced anything like and can shed some light on what I can do to solve this.

Comment: I'd start by getting rid of `Looper.loop()`.

Comment: I wrote this method years ago so can't entirely remember what that's doing however, if I remove that, it then goes into handleMessage method and throws the RuntimeException. I think I might have this method from somewhere on the web, maybe SO or some other tutorial, this is the only place though where this method hasn't worked so bit odd

Comment: "can't entirely remember what that's doing" -- you are attempting to gum up the threading system, so that this method can return a `boolean` result, rather than using callbacks, event buses, reactive programming, or other means of delivering the result.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, was one of the first things I did in Android and worked ever since, so had no reason to look at it again. I think I've fixed it now, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this from CommonsWare comment that Looper.loop is a bit of an iffy way of doing things. This was one of the first methods I'd done in Android but so I have no fixed the method to have a callback.

In the UserInterfaceManager class I've added the following:

```
public interface IDialogResult
    {
        void returnResult(boolean result);
    }
```

I have then changed the method as follows:

```
public void showYesNoDialog(String message, String title, boolean isCancelable, final IDialogResult iDialogResult)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setCancelable(isCancelable);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        iDialogResult.returnResult(true);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        iDialogResult.returnResult(false);
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
```

And the method gets called as follows:

```
uiManager.showYesNoDialog(getString(R.string.are_you_sure_you_want_to_disconnect_the_current_database), getString(R.string.are_you_sure), false, new UserInterfaceManager.IDialogResult()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void returnResult(boolean result)
                    {
                        if (result)
                        {
                            ConnectionsManager.connectedDatabase = null;
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ConnectedDBManagerHost.this, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
```